# When using JOGL which libraries should I include?

Tags: java, jogl

For completeness I have downloadded the following archive files from the JOGL website;

jogamp-linux-amd64.7z
jogamp-linux-i586.7z
jogamp-macosx-universal.7z
jogamp-windows-amd64.7z
jogamp-windows-i586.7z

Within each of these I have access to a plethora of .jar, .dll, .so etc files.

What I wish to achieve is to have one distribution of my project that will run on linux, windows and mac (32bit & 64bit), I don't want to have lots of distributions for each device.

How should the project be set up (I'm using eclipse) so that I can create one ant build and include all the libraries, currently (for other projects not using JOGL) I just create a folder called libs under the project and put all libraries I need in there then add them to the build path and include them when creating the .jar and add them to the class path. Could I do the same for JOGL? Which libraries should I include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the following libraries it will allow the application to run on Linux, Mac and Windows desktop OS's both 32bit and 64bit.

```
gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar
gluegen-rt.jar
jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar
jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar
jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar
jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar
jogl.all.jar
```